# Program crashes when inserting an item into a tree

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am writing a program with trees. The user gives string inputs and the program splits these strings into words and insert those words into a tree. The program stops when one of these words equals "eoi". When I give the first input, the v->item (actually this is root->item) is printed correctly. But when I give the second input, the v->item has wrong value (it has no longer the root->item value but the value of the new input).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;

typedef struct treeNode {
  char* item;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
  int freq;

  int rank; 
} TreeNode;

TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char* x);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    TreeNode *root = NULL;

    char str[100];

    printf("Enter input text : ");
    gets(str);
    printf("Input : %s\n", str);  
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(str, " ");
    int i,j;
    i = j = 1;

    while((strcmp(tok, "eoi") != 0))
    {           
        printf("%d %s\n", i, tok);          
        i++;
        root = insertItem(root, tok);
        tok = strtok (NULL, " ");       
        while(tok != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tok, "eoi") != 0)
            {
                printf("%d %s\n", i, tok);
                i++;
                root = insertItem(root, tok);
            } 
            else
            {
                j = 0;
                break;
            }  
            tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
        if(j == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        gets(str);
        printf("Input : %s\n", str);  
        tok = strtok(str, " ");
        i = 1;      
    }   


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char* x) {  

   TreeNode *tmp;
   TreeNode *v = root;  
   TreeNode *pv = NULL; 
   while (v != NULL) {  
      pv = v; 
      printf("v->item : %s\n",v->item);
      if (strcmp(x, v->item) < 0) v=v->left;
      else if (strcmp(x, v->item) > 0) v=v->right;
           else { 
                  printf("%s already exists.\n", x);
                  tmp->freq++;
          return root;
           }   
   }

   tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc((strlen(x) + 1) * sizeof(TreeNode));
   tmp->item=x; tmp->left=tmp->right=NULL;
   tmp->freq = 1;
   if (root != NULL) { 
      if (strcmp(x, pv->item) < 0) pv->left=tmp;
         else pv->right=tmp;
   } else root=tmp;
   printf("root->item: %s", root->item);
   return root; 
}
```

For example, in the beginning use the input: `one two`
Now the v-> item is one 
Then give the input: `five six`
v->item is five but i should be one
Then the program crashes.

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: In `TreeNode* insertItem()`, `tmp->freq++;` dereferences an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `gets()` is dangerous. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: You have debugged it through to see what happens?

Comment: @EOF thats why it crashes. Thank you very much. Now I have to find out why the wrong v->item is printed

Comment: Which compiler do you use? You need to enable warnings which will tell you that *tmp* is uninitialized.

Comment: debug, debug, debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the reuse of the buffer `char str[100];` in `main()`, as well as the dereference of the uninitialized pointer `tmp` in `insertItem()`:

In `main()`, `gets()` (which you *absolutely* should never use) fills the `char str[100]`-buffer with the first input, then you tokenize the buffer in-place, so `str` now contains

`"one\0two\0[garbage]"`.

You insert the tokens into your tree, and this works fine, since the two strings compare unequal. However, when you read the next input, *the buffer is reused*. After tokenization, `str` contains

`"five\0six\0[garbage]"`,

and the pointers in your existing tree nodes *point into this buffer*!
Particaluarly, the first tree-node has a `char *item` that points to the `"five\0"`, so the `strcmp()` compares equal, which, as pointed out in my comment, dereferences `tmp` in `insertItem()` before it is initialized.

You *probably* don't actually want to allocate `tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc((strlen(x) + 1) * sizeof(TreeNode));` in `insertItem()`, but rather

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp)); // == sizeof(TreeNode)
tmp->item = strdup(x); // or tmp->item = malloc(strlen(x)+1); strcpy(tmp->item, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact problem lies in the `insertItem()` since no memory is being allocated to `item`. You could do

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode);
tmp->item = malloc(strlen(x)+1);
strcpy(tmp->item,x);
```

The running code can be seen at http://ideone.com/nomnJ4 . Further I've avoided all complications of `gets` by using `scanf` since you need to read one word at time.

Answer (score 1):

Check below revised code. There were 4 changes that are commented on lines:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;

typedef struct treeNode {
    char item[100];     // change-1
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    int freq;

    int rank;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char* x);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    TreeNode *root = NULL;

    char str[100];

    printf("Enter input text : ");
    gets(str);
    //printf("Input : %s\n", str);
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(str, " ");
    int i,j;
    i = j = 1;

    while((strcmp(tok, "eoi") != 0))
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, tok);
        i++;
        root = insertItem(root, tok);
        tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
        while(tok != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tok, "eoi") != 0)
            {
                printf("\n%d %s\n", i, tok);
                i++;
                root = insertItem(root, tok);
            }
            else
            {
                j = 0;
                break;
            }
            tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
        if(j == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("\nEnter input text : ");    // change-3: added
        gets(str);
        printf("Input : %s\n", str);
        tok = strtok(str, " ");
        i = 1;
    }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

TreeNode* insertItem(TreeNode *root, char* x) {

    TreeNode *tmp;
    TreeNode *v = root;
    TreeNode *pv = NULL;
    while (v != NULL) {
        pv = v;
        printf("v->item : %s\n",v->item);

        if (strcmp(x, v->item) < 0)
            v=v->left;
        else if (strcmp(x, v->item) > 0)
            v=v->right;
        else {
            printf("%s already exists.\n", x);
            v->freq++;  // change-2
            return root;
        }
    }

    tmp = (TreeNode *)malloc((strlen(x) + 1) * sizeof(TreeNode)); // change-4
    strcpy(tmp->item,x); tmp->left=tmp->right=NULL;
    tmp->freq = 1;
    if (root != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(x, pv->item) < 0) pv->left=tmp;
        else pv->right=tmp;
    } else root=tmp;
    printf("root->item: %s", root->item);
    return root; 
}
```

Output:

```
Enter input text : 1 2 3
1 1
root->item: 1
2 2
v->item : 1
root->item: 1
3 3
v->item : 1
v->item : 2
root->item: 1
Enter input text : 3 4 5
1 3
v->item : 1
v->item : 2
v->item : 3
3 already exists.
----root->item: 1
2 4
v->item : 1
v->item : 2
v->item : 3
root->item: 1
3 5
v->item : 1
v->item : 2
v->item : 3
v->item : 4
root->item: 1
Enter input text : eoi
```

Comment: `v->freq++;` helped me a lot! Thank you!